# Is it possible at all to bulk-load data from an application into Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I've been looking over various questions on loading data into Firebird, and apparently it's possible to run multiple INSERT statements in a batch... if you're running a script in ISQL and all the values are written inline.

If you're trying to do this from code, of course, you have two problems here: 1) ISQL syntax doesn't work, and 2) any developer with 20 minutes of SQL experience knows that writing data values inline into your query is an unholy abomination that will summon [nasal demons,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon) cause your hair to fall out, and oh by the way leave your system open to SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

But I haven't found any solution whatsoever about running bulk inserts from application code.  I haven't even found anyone discussing it.  Apparently there's a mechanism for quick-loading data from "external tables" if you write it out to a file in the right format, but there's precious little information available on how that works, and what *is* available claims that it has problems with concepts as simple as blobs and even nulls!

So I'm just about at my wits' end here.  Does *any mechanism at all* exist to allow 3rd-party application code to bulk-load any and all data supported by Firebird into a FB database?

Answer (score 1):

1. Prepared parameterized statement in loop.
2. IBatch class in Firebird 4 OO API.
3. IReplicator class in Firebird 4 OO API which is tricky but the fastest possible option.

In any case parsing of source data format and transforming values into types supported by Firebird is up to the application programmer. There is no silver bullet that "load anything".

Comment: Interesting.  Searching for these things doesn't turn up much, especially `IReplicator`.  How do you know about these APIs?  Where are they documented?

Comment: @MasonWheeler I believe - but I'm not 100% certain - that user13964273 is a regular contributor to the Firebird code. As to the batch API, see [Support for Batch Insert and Update Operations in the API](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html#rnfb40-apiods-api-batchops) in the Firebird 4.0 Release Notes (though to be honest, I think that it is not really well-documented...).

Comment: Yes, IReplicator is used for internal purposes, it is kinda experimental and still unset so the only documentation is Firebird sources.

Comment: there is also an undocumented internal reinsert API used by GBAK when restoring :-)

Comment: GBAK in v4 uses batch API. Before that it used Message API.